# how to send and recv specific chars winsock

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I have `char* MESSAGE = new char[256];` and `char* DISCONNECT = new char[256];` however when I use winsock to send them from the client and recieve them in the server (the server has the same char names) for some reason `char* MESSAGE` intercepts `char* DISCONNECT` any help on why this is would be great!.

Cient:

```
private: System::Void Form1_FormClosing(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosingEventArgs^  e) {
         char* Disconnect = new char[256];
         ZeroMemory(Disconnect, sizeof(Disconnect));
         Disconnect = "DC";
         send(sConnect, "DC", 256, NULL);
     }

private: System::Void txtMessage_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
         if(e->KeyCode == Keys::Enter && txtMessage->Text != "")
         {
             char* MESSAGE = new char[sizeof(txtMessage->Text->Length)];
             ZeroMemory(MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE));

             string strMESSAGE = "";

             MarshalString(txtMessage->Text, strMESSAGE);

             send(sConnect, strMESSAGE.c_str(), strMESSAGE.length(), NULL);
             txtMessage->Clear();
         }
     }
```

Server:

```
int RecieveThread()
{
ZeroMemory(MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE));
for (;; Sleep(50))
{
    if(recv(sConnect, MESSAGE, 256, NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("<%s:> %s\n", NAME, MESSAGE);
    }
}
return 0;
}

int DisconnectThread()
{
ZeroMemory(Disconnect, sizeof(Disconnect));
for(;; Sleep(50))
{
    if(recv(sConnect, Disconnect, 256, NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        if (Disconnect == "DC")
        {
            printf("has disconnected.");
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(Disconnect)` is most certainly not 256.

Comment: shouldn't `strMESSAGE` in your client be `MESSAGE`?

Comment: @chris if I could select a comment as an answer I would, I can't believe I made such a noob mistake and didn't even notice. Haha thanks. Also is there any reason why after Disconnect is recieved if I  compare `if (Disconnect == "DC")` that apparently Disconnect does not equal "DC"?

Comment: @IanLundberg, Really, that fixed it? Anyway, you're comparing two pointers there, not strings. I'd highly suggest using `std::vector<char>` to hold your characters instead and either making a `std::string` out of it to compare, or using `std::equal`. If you still want the arrays, use `strncmp`.

Comment: I didn't see this before, but you can't assign to pointers to copy it, either. You should use `strncpy` for that. By this, I'm talking about `Disconnect = "DC";`. If you never need to pass modifiable characters, you can skip the vector and use `std::string` off the bat as well.

Comment: @chris yeah turns out that didn't actually fix it It just worked the first time I entered a message it went through normally but then I typed another message to send and it said what I wanted it to say if the form is closed. tl;dr problem still there :/

Comment: @chris and I need to be able to check if the value in the char array only has "DC" in it iirc strncpy just copies one char to another char? that doesn't really help in this situation unless I am missing something? also I appreciate the help so far

Comment: @IanLundberg, In your client, you assign the address of "DC" to `Disconnect`. That doesn't copy characters in; it just assigns the pointer, which means you'll definitely leak memory. Using arrays, `strncmp` will compare the strings.

Comment: @chris okay I got it working but when it does equal "DC" it repeatedly prints "blah, has diconnected." rather than doing it one time. I am not entirely sure why it does this. If you could give me an tips this is the current code I have. http://pastebin.com/Xd9ze5WB

Comment: I'm not sure, as I haven't used sockets much, but `recv` is probably not returning `SOCKET_ERROR` for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

Among the other errors mentioned in the comments, your use of `recv` is a problem waiting to happen. The `recv` function reads *up to* the number of bytes you specify, not exactly that number. If you get fewer bytes, you need to call `recv` again.

Also, *never* throw away the return value from `recv`. It's the only way to know how many bytes of data you actually got.

The TCP layer has no idea that you consider 256 bytes an application-layer message. It does not glue those bytes together. Only your code knows that, so it's your code's responsibility to put the messages back together when they are received.